# purpose of driver

Tags: vhdl

Why do we need to use driver ?

```
entity driver is 
       port ( x : in std_logic ;
              F : out std_logic );
end driver;

architecture behv of driver is
begin

        F <= x ;
end behv;
```

This segment of code, I think, has no purpose. If there, can one explain ?

Comment: If one doesn't understand what I try to ask, feel free when you say something

Answer (score 5):

It could be a placeholder of a more complex function, where the details would have to be filled in later, which you replace with a *software wire*. <s>Or it could be a one time unit delay, though in that case I wouldn't call it "driver".</s>  *edit: I made a boo boo, Brian is right.*

Comment: Can you give me  more information about " a placeholder of a more complex function" ?

Comment: @fatai - If you design top-down you may have certain functions defined and placed in a block diagram without having worked out the details yet. So instead of the actual processing which eventually should take place you simply connect input to output. This way you can already use the "driver" entity before you finished it.

Comment: @stevenh: There is no delay, except possibly a delta cycle.